# DecimalFormat uses comma separator even when the pattern specified is a dot

Tags: java

I have the below code for formatting a double to two decimal places;

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double monthlyVal = forecastReturnValue / months;
return Double.valueOf(df.format(monthlyVal));
```

The last line fails with a **NumberFormatException** because decimals are separated by a comma;

[image: Screenshot]

I am using windows OpenJDK8:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: I think I'm missing something - what is this code supposed to do? What's the point of parsing double to String and then to Double back again?

Comment: @Amongalen Long story short, I didn't write the code. it is failing on my local instance however

Comment: Double.valueOf does not parse numbers with separators.  Double.valueOf is intended to parse a string containing a number as it would appear in code, not as it would be presented to an end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the `Locale`. By default, you are connected to the Locale on your system, which return a decimal separator as `,`. Using DecimalFormat, to change, do the following:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00", symbols);
double monthlyVal = forecastReturnValue / months;
return Double.valueOf(df.format(monthlyVal));
```

IMHO, I'd recommend using BigDecimal for such use cases, as it is more accurate, less error prone, and handle easily usage of rounding, scaling and so on.

The equivalent could be:

```
BigDecimal monthlyVal = BigDecimal.valueOf(20.0).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(12), 2, RoundingMode.CEILING); // 2 is the scale. RoundingMode is up to you
System.out.println(monthlyVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DecimalFormat` ist only for formating the value. `Double.valueOf` doesn't know the format and expect a `.` if you want to parse duch string you have to use `DecimalFormat` for parsing this value:

```
return df.parse(df.format(monthlyVal));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `new DecimalFormat("0.00");` you are not specifying the separator type. You are just specifying that there should be a separator. The separator will still be based on your locale.

[Format Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) us "." as the decimal separator.

If you want to use a '.' you can change your locale.

Comment: You have explained it very well

Comment: @Laazo Can you change the "Double.valueOf" command? Then you can use the DecimalFormat to both convert to localized string, and parse the double value?

Comment: I can make changes to the code yes, I was just unable to figure out why it works for everyone else except me